# Windows 10 TP Installation error "This upgrade path is not supported."

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

So, I decide to install the Windows 10 technical preview on my PC, and, I downloaded the Windows 10 setup files. Then, I mountd the ISO as a drive with DAEMON tools pro. I then ran my setup.exe. After choosing whether to keep my files and settings (I chose keep files), I get the following error message:
"This upgrade path is not supported. Please close Setup and re-launch from the root of the media or go back and pick a different installation choice."

System Properties:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YsxI.png]
**UPDATE:** Just ran the other installer! I was just being a Derp and running the installer from resources!

Comment: [Possible solution](http://www.askvg.com/fix-this-upgrade-path-is-not-supported-close-setup-and-re-launch-from-root-of-media-or-pick-different-installation-choice/)

Comment: @Moab - There is no installprep.exe.

Comment: probably cannot be installed from a virtual drive for some reason

Comment: @Moab - People with USB flash drives seem to have this problem too.

Comment: Yeah W7 install had usb issues also, there were several fixes one was to pull the usb drive and plug it into another port, more Microsoft beta software, it never seems to be rtm.

Comment: download the 64Bit Windows 10 ISO and not the 32Bit one.

Comment: I did. The file name is Windows10_InsiderPreview_x64_EN-US_10162.iso

Comment: do you have any additional MUI packs installed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is simple. You were using the installer you would use if you were booting your computer up from an external drive! Use the other installer!

Comment: What happened here? What do you mean by other installer? The Technical Preview is now over. You can either become an Insider and use test builds or use genuine/activated Windows 10.

Comment: Well, if it's over, why are you commenting?